# ReactJS body,html height 100%

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component called 'dashboard' in my React js application. Its height is 1145 px. The height is automatic.
But the height of body and html tags is 741 px. How do I fix this?
I tried to fix it with css here but it didn't

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;  
}

.App {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Thanks...

Comment: if the height is dynamic then remove height from your css

Comment: I quite like `html, body { min-height: 100vh }` but it really depends on your situation.

Comment: `App {
  min-height: 100%
}` problem solved @azium @DBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
.App {
  min-height: 100%
}
```